# Can LDA trained with conditional expected cost of misclassification in R?

Tags: r, statistics, classification, lda

We want to minimize [ECM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2pXP.png) in LDA. But in practice I found `lda` function in R doesn't have a parameter like `cost`. I really need this misclassification cost to train my LDA model, in order to reduce my type I error in validation process. Could anyone please tell me how can I train this kind of LDA model? Also, if there's other method that is recommended other than LDA for binary classification, please let me know. Very much thank!

Answer (score 0):

I reccommend you to use first gridsearch, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/superml/versions/0.5.3/topics/GridSearchCV, to optimize the hyper parameters of the model and then check the learning curves about overfitting. I am sure that there is a similar function in R.

I found this site also useful https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-r-step-by-step/.